# npm start ERROR - can't create local server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

I am learning React, I created react app, i typed cd davidsapp, but when I run npm install i get warnings and errors, and when I input npm start, I get all the errors posted in this link. What can I do?

https://gist.github.com/DavidRNogueira/da37a599c37ad8661c55bf599b7e0751

and here is my package.json:

https://gist.github.com/DavidRNogueira/e9b2cfd67e1d9aa04c0c8af2762d08a2

Comment: it's important to know the errors you're getting when you run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to execute `npm install` if you use the recommended way of creating new React Apps (i.e. using Create React App). As per this document - https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app , the command `npx create-react-app davidsapp` should handle the installation so that you can get started with either `yarn start` or `npm start` depending on the option you choose.

Comment: I have tried without the npm install. But after reading your comment, i tried yarn start, it didnt recognize the command. But then i did 'npm start' and it worked. I have no idea how it got fixed but I have been dealing with this for nearly a week. Thank you haha!

Comment: Haha! `yarn start` may not work if you do not have `yarn` installed globally. You can achieve it like this `npm i -g yarn` (might require to run with `sudo`)